# Why is the while loop with the upper case Right is not running?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean-operations, or-operator

Below is my code :

```py
    name = input ('Whats ur name ? ')

    dtion = input (name + ' you are in the forest where do u wanna go? ')

    while dtion != "right" or dtion != "Right":

       dtion = input ("you are still in the Forest where do u wanna go? ")  

    print ("You are out of the Forest")
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `dtion != "right" or dtion != "Right"` is always `True` as `dtion` cannot be two different strings at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The condition you wrote never become false as dtion is always true for one of the condition so the overall condition always becomes true.

The condition you are looking for is like this:

```
while not (dtion == "right" or dtion == "Right"):
```

It will work like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Waqas still i am blur about the rules behind it but yeah it runs perfectly now.